# How to fix up animation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, constraints

I have `UIImageView` with moon image.
And `moonImageContainerView` is a `superView` for `UIImageView`
And I added swipe gesture to `moonImageContainerView`.

If swipe to up,

```
self.titleLabel.isHidden = false

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.moonImageContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.moonImageContainerView.center.y = self.view.center.y
}, completion: nil)
```

you can see the result with gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlzWV.jpg

---

And now, If I add just `self.titleLabel.text = "MY TOPIA"`
My animation is break.

```
self.titleLabel.text = "MY TOPIA" // Just added this line.
self.titleLabel.isHidden = false

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.moonImageContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.moonImageContainerView.center.y = self.view.center.y
}, completion: nil)
```

You can see the result with gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHgHs.jpg

Why does the `moonImageContainerView` disappear to the bottom?
How can I fix it?

Comment: is your view setup with AutoLayout?

Comment: In both cases I'd print out `self.moonImageContainerView.center.y` to see if that is changing, however, it is hard to tell since we do not have the setup of how you implemented your initialization of moonImageContainerView

Comment: @AlanSarraf Yes. I setup at storyboard moonImageContainerView's <center.y = super.view.center.y * 2.2>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use the rest setting and did not see your case.

```
    import UIKit

    class ImageViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet  var moonImageContainerView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet  var titleLabel: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pan =  UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(pp(_:)))
        pan.direction = .up
        moonImageContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        }

        @objc func pp(_ pan: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        self.titleLabel.text = "MY TOPIA"
        self.titleLabel.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.moonImageContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.moonImageContainerView.center.y = self.view.center.y
        }, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you add the center.y constrain. You are suppose to get lower image